# How to update MBProgressHud with AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: singleton, afnetworking, mbprogresshud

I downloaded some examples in order to learn Ios.

The examples include:

- AFNetworking;
- Inapp purchase (from RayW);
- MBProgressHud;

In my viewcontroller i push a UIbutton which triggers the Inapp purchase Singleton example and start download a file from my server with AFHTTPRequestOperation. This part of communication works. But what i want to achieve is to have my hud updated while downloading. As the file is >10Mb.

So, the question is how do i update the hud with the progress of the download? I try to draw it down.

- I push the button in Viewcontroller and the hud will displayed;

  - --> request will sent to the Singleton InApp helper class which handles the networking part;

    - --> After that the AFHTTPRequestOperation will be called inside the singleton class for the download of file;

      - ---> During this download i use the setDownloadProgressBlock method for the progress.

But how do i sent the progress info back to my hud in the viewcontroller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did with a similar problem, following @mattt advice.
My Singleton **InApp helper** has `productDownloadURL` ivar and a `prepareForDownload` method that returns an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` to the caller:

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation * )prepareForDownload:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_productDownloadURL]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:productIdentifier];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    return  operation;
}
```

My **RootViewController** make the request by using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and sets `downloadProgress`/`success`/`failure` blocks as below:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[InAppRageIAPHelper sharedHelper] prepareForDownload:productIdentifier];
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesRead, NSInteger totalBytesRead, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
     float percentDone = ((float)((int)totalBytesRead) / (float)((int)totalBytesExpectedToRead));    
     [(UIProgressView *)_hud.customView setProgress:percentDone];
     _hud.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",percentDone];
 }];

 [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   _hud.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"success.png"]];
   [self performSelector:@selector(dismissHUD:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
   _hud.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"error.png"]];
 }];
 [operation start];
```

**hud** is a [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). You could also enhance the progress display using `MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate` mode.

Comment: hey, was wondering as to where and how you instantiated the mbprogresshud? I'm having the same issue, the examples on the afnetworking github only uses activityindicator. i wanted to use mbprogresshud for this one.

Answer (score 2):

Make the request from a controller, and keep a reference to the operation when you create and enqueue it in a variable (you can do this by creating an intermediary operation object with `HTTPOperationWithRequest:success:failure`, and manually doing `enqueueHTTPOperation:`.

In the body of`setDownloadProgressBlock`, set the `progress` property of the progress view (you need to divide `bytesReceived` by `bytesExpectedToReceive` in order to normalize between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little bit. I've the same thing to do and I can't understand well ho to use "intermediary op. object" THX

Comment: Rather than doing `AFHTTPClient -getPath:parameters:success:failure:`, create an operation, configure it by callback blocks (e.g. with `setDownloadCallbackBlock:`), and then enqueue it.